# Is Using-Statement necessary in a PooledDbContextFactory-Scenario?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side, mediatr

I am inside a Blazor Server Application and using MediatR for Query and Commands.

```
// Register POOLED Factory in Program.cs
services.AddPooledDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
});
```

Inside the QueryHandlers i am creating a new Context for the whole operation and dispose it by wrapping everything in a using statement:

```
// MediatR Query with Result and Handler
public class GetSpecificEntities
{
    public record Query(int Parameter1): IRequest<GetSpecificiEntities.Result>;

    public class Result : ResultBase
    {
        public List<MyEntity> MySpecificEntities { get; set; } = new List<MyEntity>();
    }

    public class QueryHandler : IRequestHandler<GetSpecificiEntities.Query, GetSpecificiEntities.Result>
    {
        IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> _dbContextFactory;

        public QueryHandler(IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> dbContextFactory)
        {
            _dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
        }

        public async Task<Result> Handle(Query request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Result result = new Result();
            // !!!
            using(MyDbContext cx = await _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync())
            {
                // do different stuff with Database 
                result.MySpecificEntities = cx.MyEntities.Where(e => e.IsActive && e.Property1 == request.Parameter1).ToList();
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

**Should i get rid of the using?**

- As far i know especially the PooledContextFactory should handle the disposing and reusing of the DbContexts so that new creations are minified.
- I am afraid that i loose performance-gains when disposing it by myself too.
- On the other hand i am not sure if there could happen InvalidOperationExceptions when not using "using" (especially in a Blazor Environment).

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Should we run horses by ourself?  `using` is required when you explicitly creates DbContext from factory, it returns instance to the pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should, but can simplify it like this:

```cs
        public async Task<Result> Handle(Query request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Result result = new Result();

            using MyDbContext cx = await _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync();

            // do different stuff with Database 
            result.MySpecificEntities = cx.MyEntities.Where(e => e.IsActive && e.Property1 == request.Parameter1).ToList();

            return result;
        }
```

It's now implicit in the method: `Dispose` gets called at the completion of the code block.

`Using` only calls `Dispose` on the object, it doesn't destroy it.  What `Dispose` does is up to the object.  In the factory context it just returns it to the factory as stated by @SvyatoslavDanyliv.